# Error when adding columns to a dataframe through a loop in r

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate Jordá's (2005) stata script in Rstudio. I am trying to forward the variable UNRATE and store it in the dataframe df with the names ur1, ur2, ... ur17.
My script is:

```
library(dynlm)
library(haven)
data_monetary_shock_quarterly <- read_stata("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/LPIV/data_monetary_shock_quarterly.dta")
View(data_monetary_shock_quarterly)

# Keep only nonmissing observations in resid_full i.e. 1969q1 - 2007q4
df <- subset(data_monetary_shock_quarterly, !is.na(resid_full))
df <- df[,-1]

#Choose impulse response horizon
hmax=16

for (i in 1:hmax+1) {
  name <- assign(paste("ur", i, sep = ""), df$UNRATE[i:nrow(df)])
  cbind(df, name)
}
```

but when I run the loop it throws the following error Error

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 156, 155
```

I expect to obtain this result
[image]

Comment: I tried it and I got the following error message ´´´ Assigned data `df$UNRATE[i:nrow(df)]` must be compatible with existing data. ´´´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the use of `assign` is almost always the wrong approach. I think a better way to resolve this is to use `[[` instead.

Second, the use of `i:nrow(df)` on the RHS is killing your assignment, you need to extend the value assigned to be the same length as the number of rows. You can append `NA` values:

```r
for (i in 1:hmax+1) {
  nm <- paste("ur", i, sep = "")
  df[[nm]] <- c(df$UNRATE[i:nrow(df)], rep(NA, i-1))
}
```

A slight improvement (in theory if not in palpable performance) is to generate the offset columns and do *one* call to `cbind`.

```r
df <- mtcars[,1:3]
tmp <- lapply(1:16, function(i) c(df$mpg[i:nrow(df)], rep(NA, i-1)))
names(tmp) <- paste0("ur", 1:16)
df <- cbind(df, tmp)
df
#                      mpg cyl  disp  ur1  ur2  ur3  ur4  ur5  ur6  ur7  ur8  ur9 ur10 ur11 ur12 ur13 ur14 ur15 ur16
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9
# Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5
# Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5
# Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2
# Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3
# Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2
# Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3
# Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0
# Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4
# Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0
# Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
# Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA
# Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA
# Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA
# Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 19.7 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 15.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 21.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```